# Creating a grid to create density heatmap of a categorical value in R?

Tags: r

So I have a big dataset of points across Europe with each point representing a certain category. What I would like to do is make a grid of a certain size, ie. 1kmx1km and plot the share of each category in each grid cell.

My dataset looks something like this but with many more observations:

```
df <- data.frame(category = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C"),
                 X = c(60,61,60,56,58,61,57,61,60),
                 Y = c( 20,21,20,19,19,21,20,20,20))
```

And here is a simple illustration of the type of maps I would like, with grid cells, where the color of the grid cell indicates the share of that category in that cell.

[image]
What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: It is not clear what you want the result to look like. Please use your example dataset and show the desired result so that the question is clearer. You could use a mock-up (e.g., a screenshot from a spreadsheet) to show the desired result if necessary.

Comment: @Tripartio I updated the question and added a simple illustration of what I would like to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. I created a larger sample dataframe for a better illustration (your tiny sample skews the coordinate scales because some values are not represented):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

# Larger randomized sample data for demonstration
set.seed(0)  # for reproducibility
df <- tibble(
  category = c(
    rep("A", 200), 
    rep("B", 200), 
    rep("C", 200)
  ),
  X = c(
    # Specify each group separately to have different weights;
    # otherwise, each plot would look too similar
    sample(56:61, 200, TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3)),   # A
    sample(56:61, 200, TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.15, 0.05, 0.3, 0.15, 0.15)), # B
    sample(56:61, 200, TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.2, 0.15, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1))    # C
  ),
  Y = c(
    sample(19:21, 200, TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5)),  # A
    sample(19:21, 200, TRUE, prob = c(0.6, 0.3, 0.1)),  # B
    sample(19:21, 200, TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.7))   # C
  )
)
  
plots <- 
  df |> 
  # add n column: count per category 
  dplyr::summarize(
    .by = c(category, X, Y),
    n = n()) |> 
  # add pct: percentage of count per category
  dplyr::group_by(X, Y) |> 
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n)) |> 
  # split into groups by category
  split(~ category) |>  
  # create list of plots by category
  purrr::map(
    \(.group) {  # for each group, generate a new list element
      .group |> 
        ggplot() +
        geom_tile(aes(x = X, y = Y, fill = pct)) +
        # colour names from https://r-graph-gallery.com/42-colors-names.html
        scale_fill_gradient(low = "cornsilk", high = "darkgoldenrod")
    }
  )

# Print out the plots
plots
```

Note that all the packages I use are from the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/). It makes tasks like this much easier.

A:
[image]

B:
[image]

C:
[image]

Comment: Okay, example works great but unfortunately not on my original dataset. There I have longitude and latitude in in decimal numbers, could that be an issue? The code runs but the plots turn out blank in the end.

Comment: @starski. I spent a lot of time on this based on the example you gave, so if this solves the problem that you posted, please accept the answer. If you have a slightly different problem because your data is different, then you should post a new question with an appropriate example. If you do that, you can flag me (Tripartio) in a comment and I will try to help if I can.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77389815/how-to-produce-a-gridded-map-in-r-where-each-grid-cell-shows-the-share-of-points